# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "boost::this_thread::interruption_point()"

Tags: c++, boost

I'm building something with make and I get the following error.
I have no clue what to do and I have limited experience outside java.

I tried boost version 1.80.0, 1.39.0 and 1.46.1 but the all have the same error.

Could someone help?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::this_thread::interruption_point()", referenced from:
      boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&) in sip_client.cpp.o
      boost::condition_variable::do_wait_until(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, boost::detail::real_platform_timepoint const&) in sip_client.cpp.o
  "boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()", referenced from:
      boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(_opaque_pthread_mutex_t*, _opaque_pthread_cond_t*) in sip_client.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/sip_client] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/sip_client/CMakeFiles/sip_client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add compiler option -lboost_thread.

Update:

websocketpp comes with CMakeFiles for the example you are trying to build.  I can't get those supplied makefiles to build and I know too little about cmake to fix it.  However, I did get that example to build without cmake by running this on Linux:

```
cd websocketpp/examples/sip_client

clang++ sip_client.cpp -lpthread -lboost_thread -Wall -g
```

Answer (score 0):

cmake was not finding the boost_thread-mt library, and had to be added manually to cmake.

I added this line to my CMakeLists.txt file and it picked it up

target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}/libboost_thread-mt.dylib)